# How do I display a carousel of embedded Tumblr posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

For a while, I was embedding the 3 latest Tumblr posts on my site--a blog image, title and post URL.

[image]

The code I was using was working great:

```
<div class="blog-post-container">    

<!-- Grab the Tumblr content (last three posts) -->    
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myexampleblog.tumblr.com/js?num=3'></script>

<!-- Only display the blog image, title and post URL -->   
<script type="text/javascript">  
  var i = 0;
  $('.tumblr_post').each(function() {
    var imagesrc = $(this).find('img').first().attr('src') ;
    var titletext = $(this).find('.tumblr_title').text() ;
    $('.blog-post-container').append( "<div class=\"blog-post\"><div class=\"blog-post-image\" style=\"background-image: url(\'" + imagesrc + "\')\"><a class=\"posturl" + i + "\"></a></div><div class=\"blog-post-title\"><a class=\"posturl" + i + "\">" + titletext + "</a></div></div>" );
    $.getJSON('http://myexampleblog.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?',
    function(response) {     
       $('.posturl0' ).attr('href',response.posts[0].url);
       $('.posturl1' ).attr('href',response.posts[1].url);
       $('.posturl2' ).attr('href',response.posts[2].url);
    });
    i=i+1;  
  });
</script>  

<!-- Keep the blog images square -->   
<script type="text/javascript">

  function makeBlogImagesSquare() {
    var blogPostImageWidth = $( '.blog-post' ).width();
    $( '.blog-post-image' ).css( "height", blogPostImageWidth );
  }
  $(document).ready(makeBlogImagesSquare);
  $(window).resize(makeBlogImagesSquare);

</script>

</div>

<style type="text/css">

.tumblr_posts {
  display: none;
}

.blog {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.blog .row {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.blog-post-container {
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.blog-post {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  margin: 0 6px 80px 0;
  width: 31%;
}

.blog-post-image {
  display: inline-block;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.blog-post-image a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.blog-post-title {
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

@media (max-width : 800px) {
  .blog-post-title {
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width : 600px) {
  .blog-post {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .blog-post-title {
    font-size: 21px !important;
  }
}

.blog-post-title a {
  color: #666666;
}

.blog-post-title a:hover {
  color: #D83C35;
}

</style>
```

(Due to all of the Tumblr external resources I have to load, I can't get the JSFiddle to work :/ ).

Now I'm trying to make a **carousel of blog posts** (instead of just 3):

[image: The effect I want: a Tumblr post carousel]

- You click a "next" button, and the next 3 Tumblr blog posts load (optimally, they'd load, but if that's not possible, they could just display)
- Once you click "next", the next 3 blog posts take the place of the previous 3
- If you click "previous", the previous 3 blog posts display

**What's the best way to repurpose my code--or ditch it completely--to achieve this Tumblr post carousel?**

The things I've tried don't get anywhere close to what I want to achieve, because I'm not very skilled at JavaScript. They're honestly not worth posting.

Thanks in advance for the help, guys!

Comment: here is a working fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ub1qzh5a/. You can load js in the external resources section

Comment: I think the maximum number of posts you can retrieve is 50. https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

Comment: OK so there might be a way to do this. Firstly what if you change http://myexampleblog.tumblr.com/js?num=3 to http://myexampleblog.tumblr.com/js?num=50, will it return 50 posts? (actually it does I've just tested it) I have some code that lists post content and loads the large image into a slider and I can click through one at a time, so it should be possible to change the increment to +3 or -3 to suit your needs, but 50 is the maximum number of posts that can be returned.

Comment: @lharby I think your comment would be a lot better as an answer, with a working example. :)

Comment: @Brian, I'm not seeing anything in the results section of the JSFiddle. Am I doing something wrong? 

I'd link you guys to the live working code (for the 3 non-carousel posts), but unfortunately I'm not allowed to. 

Anyways, it works as the image shows :)

Comment: @lharby I'm absolutely okay with a limit like that. I could even go as low as 12 or so, and just disable the "next" button when there's no more posts to show.

Comment: @lharby that sounds great, I'd love to see the code :)

Comment: @lharby FYI, the reason I wanted them to load (instead of just showing/hiding) when the user clicks "next" is due to page loading time--I'm concerned about my preloader spinning endlessly while 50 images from Tumblr load. BUT I'll take what I can get, because there might be a way to get around the loading time issue!

Comment: yea the image heights are off http://jsfiddle.net/ub1qzh5a/1/

Comment: @mikedidthis yeah I would like to, but I am a busy boy in the day. I will check my code that I have and if I have some time will try and post something.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm super late to this party but I just made a tumblr-powered carousel on codepen and this seems like the perfect place to share it!
http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/pgGGPY/
It's not exactly what you want (it sounds like you just want photo posts) but it does cycle through posts with details. It also uses a carousel plugin, Slick Slider. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ 
As you can see on the codepen, I use a for loop to go through the 10 newest posts (though you can change that). I use an if statement to check if it's a photo post and put its contents in a div with a class of .newsBlock

```
if (thisPost["type"]== "photo"){
    var postContent = '<div class="newsBlock"><h2>New Photoset</h2><span class="smallText center"> Posted on ' + postDate +'</span>'+ '<img src="' + thisPost["photo-url-1280"] +'">';

    //IF IT'S A PHOTOSET AND NOT A SINGLE PHOTO
if(thisPost["photos"].length != 0){
    var photosCount = thisPost["photos"].length;
    postContent += '<div class="gallery">'

    for (var cur=1;cur<photosCount;cur++) { 
        postContent +='<img class="gallery-preview" src="'+ thisPost["photos"][cur]["photo-url-250"]+ '">';
    }
    postContent += '</div>'
} 
postContent += thisPost["photo-caption"];
postContent += '<a target="_blank" href="' +thisPost["url-with-slug"]+ '"><i class="fa fa-tumblr-square"></i> View Post on Tumblr</a></div>';
    $("#newsCarousel").append(postContent);

} //END PHOTO POST ELSE IF
```

and then I append each .newsBlock to the #newsCarousel. After the for loop is done I initiate the slick slider on the #newsCarousel

```
$('#newsCarousel').slick({
slidesToShow: 1,
```

`//Other options });`

I also made a tumblr powered photo gallery (with a lightbox) that may be inspirational http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/eJMXov

Hopefully someone finds this useful!